# Use controller properties/methods in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have various inputs (including directives that will be explained later) such as:

```
<input mask-value="ssn" validate="checkSsn"/>
<input mask-value="pin" validate="checkPin"/>
```

These properties are in the controller:

```
app.controller("Ctrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ssn = "";
    $scope.pin = "";

    $scope.checkSsn = function () { /* validate $scope.ssn */ };
    $scope.checkPin = function () { /* validate $scope.pin */ };
}]);
```

Finally, the `maskValue` directive:

```
app.directive("maskValue", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        /* does some focus/blur magic and string replacement */
        scope[attrs.maskValue] = this.value;
        scope[attrs.validate]();
    };
});
```

This works, but it seems like a misuse of Angular to me.  Instead, it would make more sense to use an isolated scope as in:

```
    scope: {validate: "&"}
```

Then I could use `scope.validate()` instead of `scope[attrs.validate]()`.  *However*, with the isolated scope I can't update the corresponding value in the controller.  Using `{maskValue: "="}` does not work because this would try to update the `maskValue` property of the parent rather than the specific value.  I think that using `{ssn: "="}` would work, but then I have to update a specific property of the controller rather than have it be set as a directive attribute which would make the directive inflexible.  Apparently using `$parent` is not recommended either.

How can I dynamically access properties of the controller inside of an isolated scope directive?

- Example working code: http://jsfiddle.net/MmyvX/
- Attempt of what I am trying to achieve (not working): http://jsfiddle.net/MmyvX/1/

**EDIT:** I can't use `ng-model=ssn`, etc. on the inputs because during the focus/blur events in `mask-value` the input's actual value is changed.  For example it may become `*****####`, but I need to store the actual value `#########` somewhere and the controller seems to be the appropriate place since the controller will use it for other reasons later.

Comment: Using an isolate scope with `=` properties does exactly what you want. Why do you say it doesn't work? Could you provide a Plunker/jsFiddle script?

Comment: @MichaelBenford I'll set one up.  `=` does not work exactly because it would update `maskValue` in the controller (which does not exist).  I could do for example `ssn: "="` but then I'm relying on a specific value.  I want to be able to update a property transparently

Comment: @MichaelBenford You can see that this works: http://jsfiddle.net/MmyvX/ -- this is my attempt in a more Angular way (I think) using isolated scope.  It does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/MmyvX/1/

Comment: maybe this? http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directives-talking-to-controllers

Comment: @akonsu I've seen that video before and it didn't help for this particular situation.  If I did `scope.ssn` in the directive I think it would work, it's just that I want to be able to update a variable-named property `scope[attrs.maskValue]` -- doesn't work because I'd need to do `ssn: "="` anyway as well as all other possible values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-app=foo>
  <div ng-controller=Ctrl>
  {{ssn}}
  <input mask-value="ssn" validate="checkSsn()">

app = angular.module("foo", []);

app.controller("Ctrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ssn = "";
    $scope.checkSsn = function () { console.log($scope.ssn); };
}]);

app.directive("maskValue", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            validate: "&",
            maskValue: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("change", function () {
                scope.maskValue = this.value;
                scope.$apply();
                scope.validate();
            });
        },
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bfDqy/

EDIT:

they say it is better to pass the expression that you want to evaluate as an argument to `$apply` because of some error handling peculiarities in Anguular:

```
var value = this.value;
scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.maskValue = value;
});
```

Comment: This actually works!  I'm a bit confused as to why though.  I guess that the `=` takes the attribute *value* rather than the attribute name for updating to the parent.  It's perfect though :)

Comment: according to the documentation, `=` establishes two directional binding with the parent scope's model. the only thing is that inside the event handler you need to call `$apply` so that it knows to update the bindings.

Comment: I have to call `scope.$apply()` after `.validate()` as well because `.validate()` updates the controller's scope (specifically it sets `$scope.error`.  Any way to avoid this or is that just expected?

Comment: unrelated to your last question: I think it is better to call `$apply` with an argument (please see my edits). I do not think you can avoid having to call `$apply` for `validate` if it changes scope. basically my understanding is that you have to call `$apply` every time you change scope outside angular's apply loop (or is it called 'digest cycle'?). you can consolidate your changes and call `$apply` once for all of them.

Comment: also there is `ng-change`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChange maybe this would work better because it might call `$apply` for you

Comment: `change` was just used for convenience for the example.  It actually does multiple separate bindings.  Is this in line with your suggestion? http://jsfiddle.net/bfDqy/1/

Comment: yes. I changed it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5Hvf/ Since your `validate` uses `ssn` that has to be updated you have to call `$apply` twice. once for `maskValue` and then for `validate`

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already got an answer to your question, but I think it's worth mentioning that since you appear to be doing some validation, you could use Angular's built-in features to do that and still be able to use `ng-model`. Here's an example:

```
app.directive("maskValue", function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return;
      var validator = $parse(attrs.validator)(scope);

      ngModel.$render = function() {
        var hasFocus = document.activeElement == element[0];
        if (ngModel.$valid || hasFocus) element.val(ngModel.$modelValue)
        else element.val('#######');
      };

      element.bind('blur', function() {
        ngModel.$setValidity('maskValue', validator(this.value))
        ngModel.$render();
      });

      element.bind('focus', function() {
        ngModel.$render();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This directive uses [NgModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) in order to work along with `ng-model` to control how the view is updated. In this contrived example, it'll simply render ######## when the element loses focus and if the validation function returns false. But when the control gets focused again, it'll render its real value so the user can change it. Notice that the property of the scope bound to the control remains intact while its view changes accordingly to the element state (valid or invalid). You can see a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bvz4JfVaLAgOoeBvJ6gD?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry but why not just do that :

```
app = angular.module("foo", []);

app.controller("Ctrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ssn = "";
    $scope.validate = function () { console.log($scope.ssn); };
}]);

app.directive("maskValue", function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("change", function () {  
                scope.validate();
            });
        },
    };
});
```

And HTML like that :

```
<div ng-app=foo>
    <div ng-controller=Ctrl>
        <input ng-model="ssn" mask-value />
    </div>
</div>
```